# Problems validating a jwt null in php

Tags: php, flutter, jwt

I'm new to JWT and doing an exercise to understand it better.

I am in a scenario that from flutter I am sending the token from the header but the token is null and I am trying to validate that in php.

When I try to do a simple validation using some method like "is_null()","$variable == null" using conditionals, the response is as if it is not null, even I show the variable and I get the null value.

The variable $token is null, im sending null

$headertoken = $headers['authorization']; dont function with "Authorization"

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code for flutter and php.

```
`// flutter code
Map<String, String> header = {
      
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
      };

      var Url= Uri.parse("http://....");
      var response = await http.post(Url,
          body:{
            'contra' : Contras,
            'corr' : Corr,
           
          },
        headers: header
      ).timeout(const Duration(seconds: 90)) ;
  var data = json.decode(response.body);
 if(data['estado'] == "ok-validado"){  
print("correct");
}else{print("incorrect");}`

// php code

use Firebase\JWT\JWT;
 use Firebase\JWT\key;    
require __DIR__ . '../vendor/autoload.php';
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');

 $headers = apache_request_headers();
 $headertoken = $headers['authorization'];

   $resultado = str_replace("Bearer","",$headertoken); 
       $resultado2 = substr($resultado,1); 

   if($resultado2 === null){
   $val = "is null";
       }else{
        $val ="is not null";
       }
   $array = array(
        'description' => $val,      
    );
    
    echo json_encode($array,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE |  JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);`
```

the reason why the validation is not working for me

Answer (score -2):

Maybe `$_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']` ?

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: i updated th code